# fake sendmail for windows

Tags: php, sendmail

I am using [fake mail for windows](http://glob.com.au/sendmail/), For long time i got a problem with the **FIRST** mail i am sending, What i mean is that for example i am using php so i will use this line:

```
mail("example@gmail.com", "hey", "bye");
```

If i will load the page with this mail function for the **first time** the mail function will return false, But the second time and third and so on it will work, **But**, After **some time** i can not determine how long exactly, I can say the gmail mail server "going to sleep", And again when i am sending a mail for the first time its like, Ohh you need a mail to send give me a second(the first mail return false), After the mail server got the second it wanted it will send the mail(return true), I did follow this [**tut**](http://digiex.net/guides-reviews/guides-tutorials/application-guides/544-configuring-php-under-windows-use-gmail-external-smtp-server-ssl.html), The error appear at the error.log is: **Connection Closed Gracefully.**, Now as i see it there is a problem on my gmail account(some setting i should change), Anyway If anyone got any idea i will be very thankful, Thank you all and have a nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After researching this bug, it seems to be a bug of the mail() function.  One alternative is to download the [phpMailer library](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer), and implement your mail function there.  The other alternative, since you say that the second time it always works, is:

```
if (!mail("example@gmail.com", "hey", "bye"))
    mail("example@gmail.com", "hey", "bye");
```

In other words, if it fails once then you try again.  You might insert a 300-milisecond pause there in case Google needs some time to come back from sleep.

Comment: Thank you Alex, At this time i am using phpMailer, But about your idea it's great i didn't think about that, Anyway about the pause just to be clear i don't think going to use fake sendmail again but for the pause is it ok to use http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php

Comment: Yes; sorry, I should have specified that.